# SQL Interleave multiple ordered tables

Tags: sql

Let's say I have 2 tables with date ordered rows like:

products table:

| date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 09/01/2021 | P1 |
| 12/01/2021 | P2 |
| 22/01/2021 | P3 |

and artworks table:

| date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 19/01/2018 | A1 |
| 27/02/2019 | A2 |
| 28/02/2021 | A3 |

Is there any way in SQL to design a query that joins the 2 tables by "interleaving" them, but takes the first 2 products, then 1 artwork, then the next 2 products, then the next artwork...and so on

The result would be like:

| date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 09/01/2021 | P1 |
| 12/01/2021 | P2 |
| 19/01/2018 | A1 |
| 22/01/2021 | P3 |
| 27/02/2019 | A2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to produce *interleaving* numbering.

For example:

```
select
  date, name
from (
  select date, name,
    row_number() over(order by date) * 10 as rn
  from products
 union all
  select date, name,
    row_number() over(order by date) * 20 + 1 as rn
  from artworks
) x
order by rn
```